# Triangles, Triangles, and More Triangles

Tags: mathematics, geometry

Which has more area, Shape A, which is one big triangle, or Shape B, where each 2 triangles have half the side length of the previous two triangles? (Shape B has infinitely many triangles.) Or do they have the same area?
[image]

Comment: What is the relationship between the side length of the largest triangle in shape B and the triangle in shape A?

Comment: From the picture it seems it is the area of a triangle that is half of the next largest triangle.  This makes it more interesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a visual proof that the area of B is

> 2/3 of the area of A.

assuming that the first triangle of B has half the edge length of A.

Picture:

> [image]
>  The triangles of B can be rearranged to fit inside triangle A, and they fill 2/3rds of each layer.

Comment: +1 This same figure is a Proof without Words by Rick Mabry: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2691318

Comment: @RobPratt Well, I suppose this is the complement of that one :-).

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the largest triangle in shape B has half the side length of the triangle in shape A:

Each triangle in shape B is $1/4$ of the area of the previous step's triangle. That is, denoting the area of shape A as $A$, the total area of shape B is

$$
2\cdot\frac{1}{4}A + 2\cdot\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{4}A + 2\cdot\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{4}A + \cdots \\\\
= \\\
2A(\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{16} + \frac{1}{64} + \dots) \\\\
= \\\\
2A(\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4^i})
$$

Since this sum [is known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1/4_%2B_1/16_%2B_1/64_%2B_1/256_%2B_%E2%8B%AF) to converge to $1/3$, the total area of shape B is

$$B = 2A\frac{1}{3} = \frac{2}{3}A$$

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Redo entire calculation

A is  bigger:

Shape A has and area of bh/2, or, 1/2 b x b sin(60) = b^2 sqrt(3)/4.

For now, ignore the duplicate sizes in B,
The first instance of shape B, B1 has area of (b/2)^2 sqrt(3)/4 = 1/4 A.
The next size of shape B, B2 has an area of 1/4 B1, or 1/16 A

The sum of a single instance of each size is:
1/4 A + 1/16 A + 1/64 A ... , or Sum 1/4^n A
B1/1-r = A/4(1-.25) = A/(3)
And we need to multiply this by 2 to account for the duplicate shapes.
B = 2A/3

B is 2/3 the size of A

Comment: Careful, the factor between consecutive terms is 1/4, not 1/2.

Comment: So, what you are saying is if X = 1/4 x Y then 2X = 1/2 x 2Y?

Comment: Comments above here are irrelevant to current edit.

Comment: That's one way of putting it.